# Azure IoT Hub Device Twin Change Notification Issues

Tags: azure, iot, azure-eventhub, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I'm trying to receive notifications in the cloud back-end when Device twin properties change. To do this I have set up a route as seen in the picture link below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKNOG.jpg

I have also created an Azure Function that triggers on the default consumer group for the built in end-point events. But when I update the device twin document for one of my device the azure functions does not trigger. And if I monitor the events for the device using iothubexplorer or Device explorer I see no "updateTwin" events at all. However it works if I send regular device-to-cloud from the device I receive those.

Im using the following code to update the device twin:

```
'use strict';

var Client = require('azure-iot-device').Client;
var Protocol = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').Mqtt;

var connectionString = '';
var client = Client.fromConnectionString(connectionString, Protocol);


client.open(function(err) {
if (err) {
    console.error('could not open IotHub client');
}  else {
    console.log('client opened');

    client.getTwin(function(err, twin) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('could not get twin');
    } else {
        var body = {
            temperature: '40'
        }

        console.log(twin.properties.reported);

        twin.properties.reported.update(body, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('could not update twin');
            } else {
                console.log('twin state reported');
                process.exit();
            }
        });
    }
    });
}
});
```

Ive also tried using iothub-explorer using the following command:
        iothub-explorer update-twin InitialDevice {\"properties\":{\"desired\":
    {\"interval\":9000}}} --login ""

Comment: for test purpose, you can use a Device Explorer (or Azure portal) for update a device twin desired properties to see a notification message in your Azure Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested with the code in your post, it works, so your Routes setup and code are correct.
[image]
[image]

Have you referred to this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46196423/how-to-implement-routes-functionality-for-twin-change-in-azure-iot-hub)? I guess the problem is similar with that.Please try to check the account location and test with Roman Kiss's suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for your response Michael. After lots of attempts trying to get it to work I removed my IoT hub and created a new one on Europe West instead of Europe North, after that everything worked perfectly. Perhaps It was the location of the service, or some other setting that I had managed to activate. Anyways, it works now. Cheers.